# Can we make delete votes work the same as close votes?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, vote-to-reopen

Normally, if users A, B, C, D, and E close a question, and V, W, X, Y, and Z reopen it again, A can't vote to close *again* (same for the rest of the original closers).

However, with delete votes, you can vote again:

[image: img of what happened]

(I blacked out all the names except mine, just in case somebody doesn't want their name here)

As you can see, I voted to delete twice, once and then again after it had been deleted and reopened.

[This appears to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431/347902) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  So can it be changed to be consistent with close and reopen votes?

Comment: Evidence that this is by design is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431/347902).

Comment: You are asking for it to be changed, why? What is wrong with the way it works now? What problems would be solved by changing it?

Comment: Close votes can be reissued 14 days later. However, that's not the case here.

Comment: This is the same request as [Restrict the delete/undelete vote privilege to once per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361933/restrict-the-delete-undelete-vote-privilege-to-once-per-post); however, that post contains a more cogent argument for implementing this.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176024/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9438/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/282094