# Restrict the delete/undelete vote privilege to once per post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges, vote-to-delete, deleted-posts

I am aware of the [reasons delete has not been restricted before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431/244695), but the reasoning has begun to unravel on Stack Overflow, where a fairly large pool of users now have access to that privilege. I give you [exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66101997/revisions)

[image: Close/delete thrashing]

Yes, we can stop it by locking it (which I did), but locks are a poor tool here because **it prevents ALL post interaction** (which isn't fair to the user, who is not part of this "meta" argument). Moreover, motivated users will simply out-wait the temporary locks.  I had to moderator delete another question to prevent the same problem. Neither solution is great. There's no real policy to quote to people doing this either, but it's becoming a more common problem.

I think the time has come to restrict delete and undelete for regular users (not including the OP) to once per post, just like (successful) closure. It's clear that motivated users with that privilege will continue to delete/undelete ad nauseum, and it actually **diminishes** the delete privilege because people who disagree will get more votes tomorrow to change it back the way they see fit. Add in [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405053/2370483) and it can prevent community consensus, leaving mods to fix it with nuclear weapons. With limited deletes on a given post it forces a detente at some point, and it's a level playing field for all.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291493/can-we-make-delete-votes-work-the-same-as-close-votes), also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9438/798831).  I have not seen posts that have been deleted/undeleted six+ times and locked twice anywhere else on SE, maybe this should be SO-only?

Comment: @Ollie I suspect this happens elsewhere (many SE sites, including some older ones, are Beta, so they have a lower rep threshold on these privs) but it's not enough of a problem for them to complain... yet

Comment: Good point.  Well, can't close-votes be re-cast after 14 days?  What if that were the case for delete-votes?

Comment: @Ollie You can only recast close votes if they age away. Delete votes do not age away.

Comment: Some posts should be deleted because they're simply a poor fit. It looks like enough people here agreed on that. Why is this question so controversial in the first place? Changing the privilege system may be fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: Machavity, the lack of aging away, in relation to Close Votes, was [discussed at some length](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8773739#8773739) in The Tavern recently; with Cat and wisdom from Shog as to why it works that way.

Comment: Just to make it explicit: I assume you mean limiting it to once *per user* per post?

Comment: @RyanM Correct. Once per user per post

Comment: @Mast because the users undeleting don't ask for merging or reopening. It's such a fringe case that should instead be used to teach people how to properly curate content.

Comment: strongly related discussion at MSO: [Rule proposal: one delete/undelete per post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407860/839601) (currently [meta-tag:featured], tl;dr: moderators try to somehow manually compensate for the absence of a feature requested here)

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks for taking care of this. I agree with the reasoning. But please change the retract UI :'( I retracted my vote by mistake multiple times. If I wanna vote to delete or retract, both show a very similar form with OK and Cancel. Just change OK to Retract for when someone wants to retract!!!

Comment: @M-- There's [a request for that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371331/244695). Worth an upvote if you haven't voted on it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This was an interesting one!

Now, if a user has a vote (deleted or not) of the same type (Delete or Undelete) on a post, they won't be able to vote that same type again. In other words:

- If a user voted once to **delete** a post, that user can't vote to
  **delete** that same post **again**.
- **Separately**, if a user voted to **undelete** a post, that user can't vote to **undelete** that same post **again**.

This should already be enabled network-wide, and [we're also deploying Delete Vote retraction slowly this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/add-the-ability-to-retract-reopen-and-delete-votes) (which touches the same code).

This change won't affect the ability of moderators to delete/undelete a post multiple times, if necessary.

This change won't affect the ability of a post owner to delete/undelete their own posts multiple times, if necessary.

Sorry about the delay in response to this one; I realize some folks are already seeing these changes today. I just wanted to make sure this feature played nicely with partially-enabled retraction before posting an answer.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Can you clarify if "*if a user has a vote of the same type (Delete or Undelete) on a post, they won't be able to vote again*" means that users who voted to delete something then cannot cast an undelete vote on it? I'm assuming you mean you simply can't cast multiple delete votes--or multiple undelete votes--on the same post, but I'm not convinced I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: Your latter comment is correct, TylerH. One cannot cast multiple delete votes, separately, one cannot cast multiple undelete votes. I'll clarify it on the answer! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Are post owners exempt from this rule? Or can I not delete my own post twice now? You only mention moderators here.

Comment: [Perhaps you'd be so kind as the answer my question today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371275/335251).  Feel free to just copy and paste.  I ask only because posting here, to a march 2021, may not be effective network wide notification.  Else, a brand new post on meta.se is perfectly fine, as well.  I don't want to make more work for you, but I would have thought you'd announce before enabling everywhere.  That led me to ask my question, linked, because of site confusion in math.se I am grateful that it is settled, but please announce it in a question/post, dated today. Thanks @V2Blast.

Comment: @Unconsidered, good question! Owners are exempt from this rule and will keep functioning as before. I'll add that to the answer

Comment: @amWhy thanks for bringing this up! When a feature is published, we respond to the original Feature Request to avoid confusion, with that said, Catija's answer was edited to link to this question, which should guide users to the FR.
Regarding featuring/making a new post: as the ability to delete/undelete a vote is only available to a fraction of our users, we believe the announcement in the Feature Request is enough for now.
Lastly, I'd like to apologize for any inconveniences the delay in this answer might have caused to you or to the folks mentioned from math.se.

Comment: Thanks, @FelippeRangel.  I see Catija updated her answer to my question to include the link here, with the decision having been made.  Thanks for addressing my comment!

Comment: It seems at least in some cases users cannot retract pending delete votes. See Tomerikoo on Stack Overflow here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53345452#53345452 regarding a delete vote on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660175/why-does-redefining-a-variable-used-in-a-generator-give-strange-results Can you confirm whether the change you made was supposed to enable retraction of pending delete/undelete votes?

Comment: @TylerH if you check the FR post for the Retract delete/undelete functionality it has more info about it, but TL/DR is we're slowly enabling that feature, currently only available in MSO and MSE.

Comment: How will the API give information about retracted delete votes? Will they appear on the timeline of a post?

Comment: @Unconsidered "Retracted" voted are effectively votes that have been deleted. So as long as someone has permission to see deleted votes in the timeline, they will see retracted ones. With that said I believe only staff currently has this ability.

Comment: @FelippeRangel OK. I often try to keep track of delete votes. I can use the API for Questions, since that will give me the accurate current active ones. But for Answers, I only have the timeline. For a < 1000 reputation point user, it's the only way I can sound the alarm that valuable content is getting removed. I can see delete votes, but I have yet to see a retracted one. May I ask if it is possible to recast a delete vote if one has retracted one? I could ask someone to test this for me by casting those votes on an "unsuspecting Answer".

Comment: @Unconsidered it is not possible to recast a delete/undelete vote after it's being retracted (that's the goal of this FR, to restrict that to once per post).

Comment: @FelippeRangel I think I found a bug. This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69732763/ tells me "you can't cast a delete vote twice" (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/aORBF.png) but the question has never been deleted and no delete vote shows up. However, in the timeline w/ votes showing, it shows my delete vote was cast yesterday. What's going on? (NB - I know the question will auto-delete via the Roomba in 2 days, but still... this should show me "you have already voted to delete the post" instead, and also display one pending delete vote.

Comment: @TylerH this is odd indeed... 

Edit: Actually I just checked the voting list, and it tells me you've voted to delete this post 2 days ago, and retracted your vote yesterday. Maybe you've suffered the same as [Make the pop-up for retracting your delete vote different from the pop-up for casting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371331/361484)?

Comment: @FelippeRangel Interesting... the timeline doesn't show a retracted vote... should it? Also, I am pretty sure I didn't retract my vote... at least not intentionally. I may have *tried* to do it but only saw the "you've already voted to delete this" message, so maybe yes it is a case of showing the wrong modal. I have been periodically testing since the rollout of the retraction feature was happening slowly for main sites.

Comment: @TylerH since a retracted vote is effectively a deleted vote, only staff will be able to see that the vote was cast and then deleted on the timeline.

Comment: @FelippeRangel OK; apparently moderators can see a second date as well, but it is not super clear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvLOX.png maybe the retraction's date stamp can have some indication (like `(R)` or something in front of the date? Ideally "Delete retraction" would show in the action type column, like "Deletion" does already)? Thanks again for the assistance here :-)

Comment: @TylerH I honestly believe those are good requests! I'm not sure when we would get to those though, as it would require a decent amount of refactoring to distinguish between votes that were deleted (maybe a DeleteReason?). If you feel strongly about them, could you please start a new post so our CMs can put it through our pipeline? In return for internet points :D

Comment: @FelippeRangel Sure thing; that's live now at this location: [Make it clear in the moderator tools when a delete vote is retracted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371582/please-add-some-indication-to-a-retracted-delete-votes-timeline-entry-that-that)

Comment: I thought this restriction applied to meta as well. This question was deleted twice [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419770/timeline#history_8251a669-3aef-4ab8-b785-9b40203c3b3a), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419770/timeline#history_e4f9ba83-bfb4-4a0e-978f-91340fd4c837), and the first delete vote was cast by the same user in both instances. Is this intentional? If so, why is it different for meta? Does it apply only to MSO, or all metas? Also, this difference should be mentioned in this answer.

Comment: "*This change won't affect the ability of a post owner to delete/undelete their own posts multiple times, if necessary.*" I think it should. At the very least a post owner should be limited to no more than two unilateral self deletes/undeletes. If you need to delete/undelete your post more than that (arguably more than once, IMO), it probably requires a moderator to determine whether that's true or whether you're just abusing the feature.

Answer (score 2):

I had considered this a natural consequence of more users getting 10k tools.

> but it's becoming a more common problem.

The initial tooling had a relatively smaller user base in mind.

> and it actually diminishes the delete privilege because people who disagree will get more votes tomorrow

So as the Q&A repositories mature (and saturate) as more users get 10k tools the tendency will be for the incidence of such conflicts to also increase at least proportionally.

Comment: How does this either answer the question by offering a solution, or argue against it? This seems to simply suggest that situation should be accepted and the FR denied.

Answer (score -1):

@Catija, one way to fairly decide how to move forward on [an eight year old problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176024/282094) is that after a certain number (twice?) of rounds of opposing actions we:

- Use the voter's *Tag Expertise* totalized, after four votes.
- Instead of always five, in some cases fewer, votes to delete or undelete - we use the totality of tag experience for one way or the other, it needs to outweigh the opposing side, perhaps by 25%.
- Subsequent reversals must be from a group of voters whose experience outweighs the previous group - that leaves things open/closed or deleted/undeleted, eventually, decided by those with the most expertise.
- People of various experience can continue to vote either way (beyond 5 votes per action) until one side of the *scale* or the other **tips** (exceeds ~25%?) in favor of one outcome over another.
- Each time the scale tips and an outcome is reached the top 5 experienced voters are retained as the users who made the decision, for the purpose of the banner and revision history.

After a certain number of reversals the ability of people to change the outcome will be reduced and the outcome will have to stand. Obviously bad tag edits not made in good faith can be flagged, and rollback wars handled by the same method.

What we end up with is the most experienced people making the decision, and people with less experience ***not*** being left out of having a say in the matter. This would reduce moderator involvement, particularly where they feel they have less experience to fairly resolve a dispute; and where locking is defeated by ardent followers and watchers.

This could also easily be applied to: [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/282094) too.

Comment: This has 3 problems, 1º the voting history has to be complete for transparency and audit by the community (so your last bullet-point is not a good idea). 2º Some of the recent delete/undelete conflicts are by users with massive tag scores, that doesn't make them right and skews power toward a few (it actually makes the problem worse because integrity and score are not correlated in any way). 3º It introduces more business rule complexity something the company has avoided in the past when possible (and there aren't enough cases to justify more complexity). 1 vote per user is simple, democratic.

Comment: @bad, None of those three problems occur, 1. it's available in the queue for some types and unavailable by design for others - if you feel it should be visible that's a new question. 2. It does "skew" towards those with high tag scores, so don't upvote them in the first place - with a high enough score they'll have a Hammer anyways. 3. No one is getting extra votes. --- Your own answer about how to resolve this would be more helpful.

Comment: I did address those issues, tag expertise is just not a good indicator. Most questions have 1 language tag but it's the remaining smaller tags that indicate expertise, there's no way to distinguish based on that alone. Besides the abuse problem seems to be with users who are overinvested in the tag, so concentrating more power on them isn't going to solve the problem. I gave my answer, which is inline with the current proposal: 1 vote per user seems good enough.

Answer (score -13):

I'm against this. It's such corner case that should be solved using existing tools. Either the question should be ineligible for deletion via reopening or, in the case of duplicates, merged with the canon question so all good content is centralized and not disseminated in several questions. This is the wrong solution for a problem which we already have tools to solve.

Comment: Note that I don't mention locking because that's the worse option. For me, locking is a temporary solution while better solutions are found, sadly implementation doesn't match this.

Comment: What would be the benefits of (un)deleting a single post multiple times? Other then starting a (un)delete war I see none.

Comment: @Luuklag none. The ones undeleting are using the wrong tools. They should've using reopen votes or asking for merge. The ones deleting are doing things correctly: they believe there's no value in keeping the post around.

Comment: Well yes, this example is a rather poor exhibition of use of privileges. But using a broader view, in a more general context, I don't see the use of keeping things the way they currently are. Being able to use multiple (un)delete votes can only lead to the poor behaviour that was demonstrated in the example quoted by OP.

Comment: @Braiam Reopening a deleted post doesn't undelete it, so I don't see what reopening would accomplish here. Some questions have value, but are not on-topic; the best path forward for those is to remain closed, but not deleted. Are you suggesting the community should change how they handle such questions (e.g. we should delete everything that is closed)? Also, merging is not appropriate for the vast majority of duplicates, even well-asked duplicates. Duplicate closure covers a broad case of "same question-itis", but merging only makes sense when answers on both Qs would make sense for either Q.

Comment: @Luuklag but I'm not talking about the example. I don't care about the example. The example is just the symptom to a bigger problem: people using the wrong tools. Why I have to repeat this again?

Comment: @TylerH I don't know how you came to those conclusions, because I'm saying that people undeleting should reopen or merge. Reopening makes the question ineligible for deleting, thus stopping the tug of war. Merging also stops the tug of war. If they believe that the post should stay, it should stay in the best state possible: open or. in the case of duplicates, merged. And yes, not all merges are appropriate because many duplicates aren't appropriated either. Read Dr. Strangedupe from Jeff. All duplicates should ideally be merged. (Also my post in MSO about this issue)

Comment: @Braiam I came to those conclusions by reading your answer. From your comment it sounds like you meant that the users casting undelete votes should cast undelete *and* reopen votes, not just reopen votes. Reopening will prevent delete votes, but what if the question is worth keeping around but not worth keeping open? The "best state" is not necessarily open.

Comment: @TylerH well, don't know you but duplicates has to be useful signpost. If it isn't a useful one, why keep it? If it's indeed a duplicate, why not merging?

Comment: I already covered why we don't merge duplicates most of the time in my original comment, but an additional reason is that multiple signposts are only useful as signposts if they're *different*, e.g. different titles or combinations of key words that a user might search for. If we merged duplicates then we wouldn't have signposts anymore, and that would open us up to even *more* duplicated questions being asked.

Comment: @TylerH what? The duplicates are so different that the answers don't apply to one another? Then they are not duplicates. Why are you making me repeat myself: not all merges are appropriate because **many duplicates aren't appropriated either**.

Comment: @Braiam Questions can be the same base question, but have different details in them. Their answers can reference those details, which would preclude them from making sense as answers to the dupe target/vice versa. They are still duplicates, but they don't make good merge candidates. I'm sure there are prior discussions explaining when to merge or not on Meta.SE or Meta.SO; search for them if you're interested in learning more.

Comment: @TylerH again, details either are irrelevant (2+2 vs 3+3) or they aren't (2+2 vs 3*3). In the later case, then the questions are not duplicates. Duplicates means: all answers for A are also answers for B and viceversa. That means that merging any way would [achieve exactly the same set of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74106/213575). Why is that hard to grasp?

Comment: @Braiam Details are not irrelevant when they cause confusion in readers. Ex: "wait, why are you talking about a header here? OP is trying to center a body element? Where did this code come from" "All my code is specific to another question but the two threads were merged". Sure, we could merge these two questions that are both "how do I center some content using flexbox", because the solution to both uses the same properties, but then moderators would have to edit all the posts from one of the threads to remove stuff that no longer makes sense in their new context.

Comment: @Braiam And once that's done, you're likely to have answers that just copy each other. Merging *all* duplicates creates a lot of work, introduces a lot of harm, and doesn't actually solve a problem. That's why it isn't done except in very uncommon cases.

Comment: @TylerH well, for answers that are basically carbon copies of each other, we have deletion. All your arguments seems to hinge on the idea that duplicate questions can have different answers, which is basically the opposite of what duplicate means. Once you get out of that absurd framework, things actually make sense. In your current framework, they aren't even close.