# Has there been a recent change in the ability to vote to delete again, after a post was undeleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

**Clarification**: This question did not promote any change, as did @Machavity's question posted eight months ago.  That post received an "answer" approving the feature request.  My question sought no feature request. This question was answered by Catija, with a link to the belated "status completed designation for a question posted 8 months ago.

So I fail to see how my question is a duplicate of that question.

---

(Start of my original question):

I searched meta.se, and the most recent policy I found which allows for repeated delete votes on the same question, I found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

However, on math.se, three users, including me, received a pop up message when voting to delete a question that was undeleted:

> You already voted to delete, and cannot vote to delete again.

This message was given to each of three of us, only after the question had been undeleted.  One of us may have voted to delete again, but three of us tried and to cast a delete vote, but were prohibited from doing so.

[This is the math.se question of interest.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285969/how-can-irrational-numbers-go-on-forever).  Mainly I'd like to ask if users now are only allowed one chance to vote to delete, or not.  If not, I am trying to understand what happened on this math.se post; is it possible that a CM intervened, that might have curtailed deletions? (Note: the time-line gives *no* information indicating action from a mod or a CM).

---

Later edit:  Please see that a [March, 2001 Feature Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361933/347474) was just now designated status-completed, as per [Felippe Rangel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277/347474).

Comment: [I doubt it's a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361933/restrict-the-delete-undelete-vote-privilege-to-once-per-post).

Comment: From [Catija](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/238039?m=53329325#53329325): _“Well... if I'm reading Jira tickets correctly, whoever gets elected [moderator in the 2021 Stack Overflow election] may never have to deal with figuring out whether someone voted to delete a post more than once.”_ They’re currently in the process of limiting delete and undelete votes to one per user per post.

Comment: It was possible for non-moderators to delete more than once as recently as yesterday on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, @Ollie, but the status on that is deferred, and no further post here, if I am correct.  I agree it is likely not a bug.  I am seeking clarification.  Note I did not select the tag "bug".

Comment: Indeed, @Robert.  As I did on on two questions yesterday.

Comment: @amWhy but you do write "If yes, is there a bug [...]" so yeah, Ollie is right to respond to that and link you to that post. That you didn't use the bug tag is... of no importance. Together with the message from Catija in the SO room Sebastian Simon just linked, it seems some clarification has arrived.

Comment: And I thanked Ollie, @Tinkeringbell.  Let's focus on the question at hand, hopefully?

Comment: @amWhy I did focus on your question, so did Ollie. You're the one that unnecessarily started about tags.

Comment: Let's not start, please.  We've gotten that out of the way; let's move on.  We *could* run a test on MSE, but that might be a little overkill.

Comment: @SebasianSimon  Thanks!  I hadn't seen the second part of your comment.  I appreciate it!  I hope such a change, if it's been made, will be announced on meta.se.

Comment: That makes sense, @Ollie.  Thanks for your assistance here, and also Sebastian and Robert!

Comment: @Ollie  Could it be possible it's being tested in math.se?  Typically we are not a test site.

Comment: @amWhy No idea, I'm not on Math.SE.  I also can't think of a reason they'd choose Math to test it on.

Comment: @amWhy please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/1017231) for why "Thanks" is discouraged. Saying that you'll respond to comments is assumed and also unneeded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict the delete/undelete vote privilege to once per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361933/restrict-the-delete-undelete-vote-privilege-to-once-per-post)

Comment: @Machavity, No it doesn't, because there was no answer there when I posted, and its to your old post.  And it took affect hours before any notification to network wide users.  However, Catija answered my question.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: FYI: Time of asking a question has no influence what so ever on it being a duplicate or not. Closing questions as duplicates is merely to keep the answer in one place, as not needing to duplicate it. So you can close old questions as duplicates of new questions, or the other way around, that makes no difference.

Comment: @Luuklag  Thank your for commenting and responding.  But my question remains different from the question cited as a duplicate.  Mine is not a feature request.  Mine does not support the action proposed by Machavity.  I did not make time of post a centerpiece for my explanation.  But my question and Machavity's are without question, distinct.  And it was answered here satisfactorily.  Again, thank you for your interest.

Comment: @amWhy I didn't take any stance on weather or not this question is a duplicate. I was just pointing out that there is no need for chronology when closing as duplicates. Your comment to Machavity has this as its main argument, hence my reaction.

Comment: Good point, @Luuklag.  I'm used to explaining that same thing in math.se, so I should not have mentioned "timing" as a factor.  I was merely trying to give a timeline for the course of events today, why I asked when I did, etc., without inferring that "timing" was relevant.  But I get that that's likely what it looked like.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The CMs have no way to manually override deletion permissions on a per-post basis - short of doing what any mod could do and locking the post - which leaves a post notice explaining the action.

As hinted at in the comments, this was a [requested change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361933/restrict-the-delete-undelete-vote-privilege-to-once-per-post) that has been working its way through our backlog and it was built last night. The change wasn't announced because there was some confusion about whether it was behind a setting that prevented it from being live on the network or not.

We'll get the update out for the Feature Request shortly with information about implementation.

---

As noted, this change has been completed by Felippe in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277/284336) to the linked question.

Comment: Thanks, @Catija!  I saw the link to your chat comment.  So it doesn't surprise me.  I was confused, that's  all, because changes are usually announced before or simultaneously on meta se.  And I really tried searching, expecting, sort of, that there'd be other similar questions from users on other sites.

Comment: No problem! There was a mixup internally and some confusion but we'll get things straightened up soon. Appreciate the patience on this. :)

Comment: [The response to the FR has now been posted (by FR).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277/335251)