# It's possible to retract and re-cast a delete vote on answers, contrary to the tooltip's advice

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, vote-to-delete, retracted-delete-votes

When retracting a delete vote, the following popup is displayed:

[image: Popup displayed when retracting a delete vote]

To quote the text directly:

> rpg.stackexchange.com says
>
> Retract your vote to delete? You won't be able to vote again on this post.

This, however, is inaccurate, or it's at least inaccurate for me, right now. Your delete vote can be retracted and reapplied on answers only (delete votes on questions behave normally). This is just a formal request to have this fixed, as the ability to vote to delete and undelete was [changed to only be allowed once per post per vote type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277/622284).

Comment: I once tried a while back to recast a delete vote I'd retracted and I wasn't allowed. I think it's a bug that you're now allowed to recast them.

Comment: Undelete votes cannot be recast, so those are working as intended.

Comment: As Sonic noted, you shouldn't be able to re-cast your delete vote once retracted. I've confirmed that I can re-cast my delete vote multiple times after retraction on some of the lower-scoring answers in the formatting sandbox here  (which is a definite behavior change), so I've reformatted your question as a bug report as opposed to a feature-request, as it was very intentionally changed awhile back to be one vote per delete vote type per user. You're free to revert the changes if you feel they go against your intent, though!

Comment: Looks like I was mis-remembering: it was indeed an undelete vote I was trying to recast after retracting, not a delete vote. Still, I think it's a bug that it's inconsistent for both types of votes.

Comment: No repro on Stack Overflow. I get "You can't vote twice to delete a post" after retracting my delete vote: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8wlJ.gif

Comment: @41686d6564 I'm still able to reproduce https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1STE.gif

Comment: @Spevacus Weird. Might be the case with answers only? Are you able to repro on a question?

Comment: @41686d6564 Yep, that appears to be the problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNPbN.gif This only seems to work on answers.

Comment: Isn't being able to recast a *retracted* delete-vote desirable (with some upper limit, so people don't do it 100 times on the same post to just be annoying)? The thing we don't want is to be able to cast a second delete-vote when a user's earlier delete-vote successfully participated in deleting the post.

Answer (score 18):

This has been fixed in production.

Thanks to all the folks who brought this to our attention, both here and privately via chat.

The edge case was introduced a couple months ago when handling [voting to delete a question after it has been reopened and reclosed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/voting-to-delete-a-question-after-it-has-been-reopened-and-reclosed) where we checked if the most recent delete vote was more recent than the post closure date.  However, answer posts don't have a closure date, so when comparing `DateTime.Now > null`, it evaluates to `false` and made it seem like the close vote was from a previous close/re-open cycle.

I did some queries to assess impact. We have at most 133 cases of multiple delete votes per user per post across all sites. Of those, only 12 voted to delete the same post more than 2 times – so most were likely accidental usages with little/no impact. And of those 12 with >2 votes, most were from users who had pro-actively reached out to us to let us know or were testing in sandbox.

We'll review the other cases to make sure there's no impact to users, but should be all set otherwise.