# Has the warning/question about retracting delete votes been (intentionally) removed?

Tags: support, user-interface, vote-to-delete, retracted-delete-votes

As far as I remember (and [It's possible to retract and re-cast a delete vote on answers, contrary to the tooltip's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377412) confirms this) there used to be a warning/question whether to retract delete votes.

But it seems it was removed in the past month or so. On Politics and Skeptics I accidentally retracted my delete votes to various terrible Qs because I clicked on the thing twice... and I can't recast a delete vote apparently.

Was this UI "improvement" intended?

Comment: If it makes any diff, using Google Chrome "103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)".

Comment: If it's of any help, the most recent place where it happened to me is on https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74369/why-do-california-voters-support-looting-under-950-de-facto-legal (There's one pending delete vote, but that's not mine.)

Comment: Can you try closing and reopening Chrome? Also, see if you get other dialogs (click the "Add Another Answer" button on a question you already answered and it should ask you if you're sure you want to start writing another answer).

Comment: @Laurel: the dialog for close votes works fine. And yeah restarting Chorme fixed the delete dialog on Skeptics. I cannot find a suitable Q to re-experiment on politics right now.

Comment: Found one. It works on politics too now.

Comment: There's a claim it was fixed:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371279/282094 and that the two dialogs are very similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371331/282094

Comment: @Rob it was never fixed because there was never a bug.

Comment: @Rob I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggestion (in comments) to restart Chrome fixed it for me, meaning the dialog comes up now.