# Automatic retracting delete and undelete votes to questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I suggest automatic retracting all delete and undelete votes to every question and answer which has no delete or undelete vote in the last 365 days. This is to prevent deleting and undeleting the same post many times and to cast wrong delete and undelete votes.

If an user's vote is retracted, he/she can again cast the vote if he/she wants.

Comment: [_Heavily consider not requesting a new feature if you're new_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189)

Answer (score 4):

It's only possible to [vote to delete and undelete once per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361933/restrict-the-delete-undelete-vote-privilege-to-once-per-post) unless you're a moderator or it's your post so this is solving a problem that doesn't exist.

If it's your post and there are no restrictions on deletion such as existing answers then why shouldn't you be able to delete it? Let's imagine you asked a question or answered one, realised that your post had problems and so deleted it in order to fix those problems. You can only do that once? That doesn't seem like a useful restriction.

If you're a moderator then you need to be able to take moderation actions on a post regardless of any previous actions you may have made.