# How to reword this question so it's not asking for a list?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

How do you reword this question so it's not asking for a list which is a reason to close or put a question on hold.

[Any full web pages or examples using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351053/any-full-web-pages-or-examples-using-twitter-bootstrap-3-0)

The question read:

> I know Bootstrap 3.0 is still work in progress. I was wondering if there's any example site or page template using it?

Comment: Well, it's kind of hard to reword a single sentence that's asking for examples... Is there any other sort of question in there?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to tell you how to ask a question that is off-topic in a way that it's not off-topic.  You can't; it's off-topic.

Comment: Did you try using it? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Even if it weren't asking for a list, it would be too broad.  It seems you're just looking for general information about [topic].  That's not appropriate for SO.  You need to have some much more specific question related to [topic] to ask the question.

Comment: Can we please stop ████ing deleting questions while we're still talking about them?

Comment: @pekka: I undeleted, and locked it for an hour.  Is that long enough?

Comment: @Robert, not to put speak for Pekka, but an hour might barely be long enough, it really depends on whether this discussion goes anywhere or not.

Comment: @Robert thanks! That sounds perfect (although jball has a point, but you have to draw the line somewhere.)

Comment: @jball: OK, locked for 1 day.

Comment: @animuson You want it as question: Do you know of any sites..?

Comment: @Tony with 5k rep you should know better.

Comment: @Robert Why is it off-topic? Bootstrap is a html template which is web design which is related to SO. There's even a tag for it.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar 5k rep means nothing. FYI, 99% were from asking.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: Have you read the close banner that was attached to your question?  What part of it is unclear?

Comment: @Robert It was useless and I didn't agree with it. Check this out also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186557/put-a-question-on-hold-when-it-does-start-to-attract-opinionated-answers-and-spa

Comment: Your agreement is not required.  This is not a new thing; list questions were never allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, not never, just not for a number of years now.

Comment: @Pekka웃 perhaps you want to add an answer to [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166329/can-something-be-done-to-prevent-delete-votes-when-a-question-has-reopen-votes-o) if you want to set a policy of not deleting questions being discussed on meta.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Did you just delete it again?

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes.  The text of the question is already copied here.  There's no point in preserving it.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Ah, makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

The question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow and I can see no way to make it one.

Consider instead:

- asking at the project's support forums or mailing list (if such a place exists)
- finding other places that have discussion about the project
- asking in the related Stack Exchange chat room
- contacting the project's authors
- Googling around for uses of the product, e.g. blog entries

Answer (score 1):

My best shot would be to reword it to something like "Hello World/minimal example for Twitter Bootstrap 3.0", but even that is dicey. What would really be useful is addressing a specific problem you are having trying to include Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 in a template or webpage, which would I think naturally lead to a minimal working example as an answer.

Comment: I don't have a problem yet. I would like to see some sites or examples. It's like window shopping. You may check out a new gadget. It doesn't mean you need one right now.

Comment: Right, so maybe it's not the right time to ask an SO question about it. If you still feel compelled, ask about a specific challenge you forsee from your window shopping. But generally, a "help me window shop" question seems off topic.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do? What problem are you trying to solve? Is this idle curiosity, or do you suspect you might have a use for Twitter Bootstrap 3.0?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.