# Is it reasonable to close a question if is intended towards discovering new frameworks?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, not-constructive, list-questions

I asked [ServiceStack.net equivalent in other platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14806748/30594) question in SO to learn more about frameworks which solve a particular problem. I feel this can be answered with references, or specific expertise and should not be closed.

Please let me know why my understanding of SO is flawed and detail on why this can be closed as not constructive?

If you think this will lead to List of 'X' which gets outdated over a period of time, I feel it would still act as a reference as at this moment I don't think any such framework exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166325/158605) a very similar question to this one last week.

> It was probably considered "polling" since you were asking for a
>   framework to do something, and the details about that framework
>   weren't clearly pointed out (many people don't think to read the tags
>   for important info about the question).
>
> Most polling questions that simply ask for a framework or a library
>   end up as a big list of links pointing to everyone's favorite
>   framework/library, which is typically why those questions get closed
>   as "not constructive".

SE doesn't want to get turned into a link farm, so it tends to discourage questions that only ask for links.

A better way of phrasing your question would be to outline the problem you are trying to solve (Metadata pages for all registered formats, and support for additional specific end-point types), and ask how that can be accomplished in your technology of choice.

You may get an answer pointing to an existing framework, or you may get an answer explaining how you would do that yourself in your code. But the end result is an answer that anyone can use when they come across the same problem.

That said, I have seen a few questions asking for frameworks survive, however they are usually very specific about the exact features of the framework/library wanted, and are phrased to elicit the name of *that one framework* that matches the description, and doesn't result in a huge list of links going to many different frameworks that may or may not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @Rachel for explaining it. I think this makes sense to me. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 13):

[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is a blog post that discusses such questions and why they are not suitable for Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in general.

The gist of it - there is no definitive answer as people answer with their subjective favorite. It becomes "discussiony" and in that respect not suitable. And answers become stale as new `<product>` becomes popular.

Comment: If I had to summarize our network in a single word, that word is “learning”. People come to our sites to learn about topics they are passionate about. As the old Chinese proverb goes, “Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.” Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning — yes, even the shopping ones. And I felt this would help me learn about new frameworks in new platforms.

Comment: @Ramesh - The network is actually more narrowly defined than "learning". It is good questions and good answers to them. We have defined those over time (the "good" part). We have found that resource questions like the one asked about here are not a good match - they tend to gain lots of _bad_ answers and no _definitive_ answer, which are things we see as _bad_.

Comment: @Ramesh - give a man a list, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man how to find the right tool *himself,* and you feed him for a lifetime. I love shopping questions myself, too, but they are of very questionable *learning* value. "xyz is the bestest tool use it" doesn't really *teach* much.

Comment: @Pekka웃: it teaches you about bias.

Comment: @Pekka The problem is I am not able to find the right tool by searching it in web. It would be of great help where some one from community can point a tool which can do what I am looking for. Just closing the question as not constructive **will not teach a man how to find it**

Comment: @Ramesh - Nor would asking for a tool teach you how to find it.

Comment: @Oded I did my research and still not able to find it. I am not just asking what are the best Restful frameworks available in the world. I had a specific requirement. I am not able to find it. Either community should correct me and let me know place where I can learn something similar or outright mention so and so doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, for argument sake How will I do this in X questions can also be found at respective language / tool documentation site. Still we have it here. We can say, you need to learn to search and not closing out those questions. I get this kind of error questions can be closed saying, you need to learn to debug instead of helping the person with answers.