# Question doesn't show up in unanswered listings

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Recently I've asked a question. I received 3 upvotes, but no answers yet. The question, however, doesn't show up in the unanswered question listings. Is that correct?

I couldn't find this issue in the faq section.

This is the question that didn't show up:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359476/approach-to-submitting-forms-from-a-multi-platform-native-hybrid-app-with-unstab

Comment: Was an answer ever posted and deleted?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: Now that I look at your question, it appears that any answer could be highly subjective and there will be no one correct answer. You might want to consider rewording it as it feels like a software/framework shopping question which are generally closed. For more information, check out the following question: [why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is listed in the unanswered queue.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=31&sort=unanswered) if you view 50 questions per page. Currently top on that link.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=51&sort=unanswered) if you view 30 questions per page. Currently 2nd from top on that link.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=101&sort=unanswered) if you view 15 questions per page. Currently 2nd from top on that link.

Obviously, the place in the queue will change after I post this answer. Look in and around those page numbers and use the browser find function to look for your username.