# Unanswered question with deleted answer not showing

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

When I go to all [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) (Questions with no answers) and scroll down till I have seen all questions with 8 votes, I don't see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943670/accelerating-matlab-code-using-gpus) there.

However, when I then click the matlab tag and look at [unanswered questions tagged matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) I find that the top one has 8 votes and 0 answers. The description of this section is: Questions with no upvoted answers

I have looked around but did not find a question like this on meta yet. Furthermore the question is already at 7 or 8 votes for at least a day (probably longer).

**UPDATE**

A moderator confirmed that the question has a deleted answer.

I guess the question is now whether this is a bug, or that it intentionally does not show the question anymore. If I could choose I would say this calls for a fix.

### UPDATE 2

I just noticed that this question is now showing up under 'all unanswered questions'. Just not sure whether it is because the functionality has changed or because something happened to the question.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171892/question-doesnt-show-up-in-unanswered-listings?rq=1

Comment: There is a deleted answer there.

Comment: @Oded I guess I suspected that, so is it a bug that deleted answers prevent it from showing or is this done intentionally?

Comment: Not sure, Dennis. That page has been there for quite a while and this may indeed be an unintentional bug.

Comment: Confirming this is not intentional. We are looking into it.