# How can I ask for a question to be updated / reopen it for updating?

Tags: support, questions

Some questions here have time-related answers due to the ever changing nature of code.

Specifically, I would like an updated answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853295/javascript-build-tools but don't want to 're-ask the question'. The highest answer is 'buildr' but that has since been not supported, e.g., one of its main libraries no longer is on npm and therefore this can't all be installed via npm.

How should I ask for this then?

Comment: `The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.`  That's because it's a non-constructive shopping question, and should be closed, except there's a bounty on it now >.>

Comment: Sorry, I tried, good luck on finding what you need.  (I did start the reopen vote, so you might get lucky there).

Comment: "Some questions here have time-related answers due to the ever changing nature of code."  That is THE definition of "too localized" and is not a valid SO question.

Comment: @LanceRoberts You *know* that it's not constructive.  There is no question whatsoever that it's not constructive and shouldn't be opening.  It is **completely inappropriate** for you to vote to reopen such a question.

Comment: There are evil people on SO who delete things that don't appeal to them, even though policy would have them be locked for historical purposes.  They've taken clean-freakness to a new level.  They seek perfection of appearance instead of perfection of helping people.

Comment: Wow, @Lance, _evil_?! Is it evil to require a membership for a library? That's about as deep a restriction as deletion actually makes. It's still completely accessible to hundreds of people. It's just not publicly available. You're going over the top on this one.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, no, you can only see it if you have a link, it's not searchable like a library.  Many feature requests out there on that.

Answer (score 11):

The fact that this question needs to be updated, and will continue to need to be updated for its entire lifetime, is a very strong indicator that it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow. It is, in fact, what we call a ["shopping question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -- a request, not for a self-contained explanation of or solution to a problem, but for a list of resources or tools.

In the general case, when you would like more or different details than are provided in the answers to an existing similar question, you have two choices. You can place a bounty on the question, which will make it more visible for a week and perhaps encourage new answers with the extra reward available. It's also possible to ask a new question, *carefully* and *thoroughly* making clear the differences between the older post and your new take on the issue. The preferred option is the bounty, however. See also [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046), which also addresses questions that do have answers.

In this particular case, however, the question should not be hosted on Stack Overflow, and reflecting that, it should and has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

The question is already asked and re-asking the same question is **not** a good idea.

In this case what you could do is :

- Place a bounty on the question to draw attention on it.
- Explain in the bounty content why this question needs a new answer.

Comment: The second option sounds like a bad idea. Placing a bounty is the way to go.

Comment: I won't argue with you since you've been long enough here to know how it works. Can you please explain why it's a bad idea ?

Comment: Oh boy, you are putting way too much faith in me making any sense. :) The thing is however that you would like new attention for a question. Just editing a question with "I want a new answer, because the others are outdated" does not improve the question. And given that it's not the OP, appropriating a question in that manner doesn't seem appropriate. We have an excellent tool to achieve the desired attention, leaving the question in tact. It's the bounty. If you don't have reputation to spend, you could look for things to improve in the question asked and hope for the best. But that's it.

Comment: @Bart Thanks it's clear now. I was going to ask why not to edit to explain why it needs a new answer. Only to realise you can explain why in the bounty itself.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I don't have the rep to pay for a bounty. now what?

Answer (score -10):

**You can place a bounty on it.**

I went ahead and did that for you, good luck.

Comment: Should that be "You can ask me to place a bounty on it"? Or are you not planning to make this a general thing? ;)

Comment: @Bart, "not planning to make this a general thing", just felt like it this time.

Comment: Grf.  You bountied that thing?

Comment: That's not a bounty. That's protection money for a shopping question.

Comment: Not any more. Bounty refunded, question closed.

Comment: How would an updated answer get added if the question was closed?  It's a hole in the SE system.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that's sad that you did that, really sad.

Comment: "How would an updated answer get added if the question was closed?"  Answer:  it doesn't, because **these types of questions aren't appropriate for SO anymore**

Comment: That's one of the main reasons why this type of question doesn't work on SO. They're even less up to date than search engine results or Wikipedia.

Comment: @LBT, maybe someday you need to put yourself in another's shoes and think about questions that you really need answers for.  As someone who has needed answers in the past, I have sympathy for those who need them now.

Comment: @Mat, yep, you're right about that.

Comment: That's funny, Lance, I was thinking how sad it was that you put a bounty on it to protect it from closure.

Comment: How does bountying a Not Constructive question help new users learn how the site works?  You might as well not have guidelines at all

Comment: @JoshCaswell, it's not sad to pay it forward, it's the way people should act all the time.

Comment: I prefer to pay it forward by helping to curate SO rather than insisting that everyone who can type a question mark has some inherent right to time and space on the site.

Comment: Lance, you have 46k rep on meta.SO, and the question is *obviously* both NC and TL.  Can you please explain a bit why you thought this is a good/valid question?  Do you think we should make exceptions to these rules when someone specifically asks on meta as part of "paying it forward"?  Are you just interested in the answers and hope to get one before it closes?  Was it an error in judgment?

Comment: @LanceRoberts - or you could honor the rules of the site instead of voting to re-open every question that gets closed.  I sincerely believe that one of us will eventually be suspended, either you for abusing your Re-open vote privelges on questions you **know** are no longer appropriate but continue to do so, or me for eventually **completely** freaking out and writing a 1000-word rant against you.

Comment: Okay, so it seems your philosophy is that SO is a good place to perform random acts of kindness. I agree that the goal should be more good answers getting divvied out. But I don't agree that arbitrary or fractured rules is a good way to go about this. We would be Yahoo Answers if we had free answers for all. Then no one would get answers and that would make me sad. I don't think isolated "random acts" are harmless. SO subscribes to broken windows theory.  So please stop breaking windows and encouraging people to post Yahoo-answers quality questions because people like you help them get lucky.

Comment: Furthermore if you *disagree* with everything I just said, I ask that you make a constructive case for this on meta, so that the rest of us may get on board with your more forgiving standards. Excuse my harshness but looking through your meta participation this seems to be a pattern. Your strategy seems to be just doing whatever the heck you want and leaving the rest of the community to clean up.  If we're wrong, make the case. If you're wrong, amend your behavior.  This passive aggressive middle ground is not acceptable.

Comment: Before we get into too much of a hubbub, keep in mind that as with upvotes or downvotes, users are fundamentally free to vote how they see fit. Whether we like it or not. And given that a single user does not have the power to single-handedly reopen or close questions, there is no single user to blame. If there is any confusion regarding our motivations to close, or even disagreement, all we can really do is clearly and constructively explain ourselves and hope for the best. In the end we still seem to be doing just fine, even if we don't always like how we need to get there.

Comment: @djechlin, NO, my policy is do what's right, no matter what the opposition.  That question while it may not have met today's standards should have been locked for historical purposes at the worst, but of course that's one of the holes in SO is that questions like that that need updating aren't able to be.

Comment: Why locked?  Locked is strictly more restrictive than closed, which you were opposed to.  Locked = closed and furthermore no community ability to reopen, no further comments or votes added.  I think you misunderstand what close is for.  It's not for saying "this question is worthless information," it's saying "this question does not meet today's standards" - and is not endorsed by SO as having good information, being answerable, being a good example for future questions, etc.  Which it sounds you are agreeing this question falls under.  Why is close not the right thing to do to it?

Comment: @djechlin, actually, locked is what we're supposed to use for "this question does not meet today's standards", because if it met yesterday's and is drawing people into the site and giving good information it should be kept around.  They call it an __historical lock__.  The problem with close is that too many people treat it as a path for deletion, so then good posts go away.  There are many posts on Meta about this problem.