# Where should I ask my not so specific question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to know which forum, in the Stack Exchange multiverse, is the most appropriate to ask questions like...

> I am new to working with csv files in perl, Can someone please point me to any good references on the subject?

I know questions like these are less specific and I will get yelled at on most of the forums I use within Stack Exchange.

Comment: That is off-topic on ALL SE sites.

Comment: And Stack Exchange doesn't have a forum.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just Google [perl csv tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+csv+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)?

Comment: AS others have said - this kind of question is not suitable to the Stack Exchange question and answer model. We have tried reference questions before and it has not worked, so these are now no longer allowed.

Comment: Okay I understand , thanks for clarifying...

Comment: In every SE site where the tooltip before you choose the title doesn't say - Be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be appropriate in chat, but isn't suitable to a Q&A system expecting answerable questions.  This falls under the category of [shopping list questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) - ultimately generating lists rather than answers.

In general, non-specific discussions are appropriate to chat, although in this case, I have to agree with Bill the Lizard - what's wrong with google?  If you're looking for curation, understand that will go out of date very quickly.  If you're just looking for a place to start, look to the webz.