# Is there any Stack Exchange site for home decoration/organization questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know that *[Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)* is for construction and serious DIY.  Is there a place I could ask questions such as:

1. What kind of bookshelf should I get to fit this narrow space?
2. What size/color rug should I get?
3. What's the best way to hang this light?
4. How should I organize these kitchen tools?
5. What kind of stain should I use on this bench?

I guess #3 and #5 could be on *Home Improvement*, but what about the others?

Comment: Those all look like opinion questions to me, except (maybe) number 3.

Answer (score 8):

In order as listed in your question;

1. Is a shopping recommendation and would likely be off topic on any Stack Exchange site
2. Is a subjective question that only you can answer due to personal preferences
3. Would likely be suitable on [Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)
4. Is a subjective question that only you can answer due to personal preference
5. Would likely be suitable on [Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) but could also be seen as subjective depending on context (obviously certain stains are better for certain purposes, it would be down to the wording)

In general, shopping recommendations are off topic on Stack Exchange - for more information, see [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

I'd also recommend having a read through this blog post: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: 5 could be non-subjective if asking what *type* of stain, rather than what color/opacity. Some are objectively better for outdoor purposes, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks - re: #2 - what about something like "Based on my couch/coffee table configuration, what is the recommended rug size and placement?"

Comment: It's still pretty subjective even in that form to be honest - some people will like large rugs, some people will like small rugs, some people will like rugs that completely fill the gap between the two pieces of furniture, etc

Answer (score 5):

Not really.

- 1 : Closed as opinion based
- 2 : Closed as opinion based
- 4 : Closed as opinion based

Like you said 3 & 5 *could* be asked on home improvment although I doubt 3 would be well receive (questions with *best way to* tend to go for opinion based answers.

Decoration and organization are all up to the taste of different users so I don't think there is a possiblilty to build a good site around this (building one because none exists at the moment).