# Where to ask questions about personal life decisions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I was searching through the existing “[Life & Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts)” SE sites, but I couldn't find one which I thought was suitable for this type of question.

In a short version (which would not be a good question just like that, I know), I'd like to ask the following:

> Many people are sooner or later confronted with life-decisions and what to do about the future. Especially when finishing college it's often hard to decide where to go and what to do, since you've got hundreds of options.

In short, it's about how to deal with the [paradox of choice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VO6XEQIsCoM) when it comes to big life decisions like career, relationships and so on.

Comment: Sounds like something that would be off topic on every SE site.  Try Yahoo Answers.

Comment: As I said, the question as I've written it here would be OT and "bad". It's more like where to ask question about ones personal life.

Comment: Every site I'm on that has the potential to attract "what should I do?" questions (religion sites and workplace, for instance) considers these off-topic.  Questions like this are either not answerable (opinion-forum stuff) or too localized.

Comment: Hope we have a place because I plan on giving the worst possible advice at all times.

Comment: @Servy I swear every time I stumble onto Yahoo answers I am filled with rage at some of the garbage that not only gets offered up as an answer but at the sheer ignorance of people accepting said garbage as if it were the gospel truth.

Answer (score 7):

Nobody on any SE site can help you make a decision. However, people can help you gather the information you need to make a decision. You can construct a number of factual simple questions, whose answers you need to make this choice. For example, are you wondering:

- if people with degrees in whatever you have a degree in can work in a particular field? Can earn enough to support a particular kind of lifestyle?
- if it is warm year-round in a particular country?
- how easy it is to travel from a place you are thinking of living, back home to visit family?
- whether it's true you should have your first child by age 30?

Is there a particular program (eg a graduate program in another country, or a government program to encourage doctors to move to small towns, or whatever) that you would like to know more about?

So many questions are no doubt swirling in your head. You have so many options and you want to learn more about all of them. So do. Ask tens, dozens, hundreds of questions here. Just make sure not one of them is "what should I do?". Each question should stand alone, be on the right site, and ask something that can be accepted as the right answer. That means generally more "what aspects of X are important when evaluating Y",  "what is the average high and low temperature in Z", "what is the fastest route between A and B" and less "what is the best Y", "is Z a warm enough place for me to live" and "are A and B easy to get between" - ask for facts. You do the concluding from those.

See also [my answer to Why Are Shopping List Questions Bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185482/147247) even though yours is perhaps not a shopping question.

Comment: "what is the fastest route between A and B" seems to be a question for Google Maps, not Stack Exchange

Comment: @JanDvorak not if the route involves planes, ferries, trains etc. If you move to B, how hard will it be to come home to A for the holidays? Finding out about transport routes and costs is part of working that out.

Answer (score 1):

It's not on topic for any SE site, as it is asking for personal recommendation and could turn into a polling question. You could try creating one on Area 51, but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't go anywhere