# Getting somewhat subjective advice about software development

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know this isn't allowed on Stack Overflow, but I was hoping there was a section on Stack Exchange that would allow this question.

I just need advice for my future career: Currently I'm enrolled in a computer science degree, and I'm not sure what to do next without wasting time. For example, I wanted to learn to make a website (HTML, JavaScript, and CSS) and create a game app (Java, Android SDK) as well as a desktop game (C++).

So basically I wanted to know if I should bother learning all of it, or focus on one thing and what do companies look for in employees. Where can I get this kind of advice (among other questions like this)?

Comment: I don't think anywhere on SE would be suitable for this kind of query

Comment: [You can post it on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-advice-would-you-give-to-a-23-year-old-software-engineer-working-at-a-hot-tech-company-to-have-a-secure-job-in-their-40s?share=1)

Comment: Yes, I hope you did at least try Quora. SE is for specific questions, the more specific the better. It isn't a place for open-ended personal discussions about the profession. in fact, SE can be a very rude place and those downvotes always hurt, lol. Oh, and I see it was a duplicate too, omg. I have lobbied to make it friendlier to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a subjective decision to make, you make it based on many tiny pieces of information. Say your question is "should I go on holiday to the south of France?" Nobody can answer that for you, any more than they can advise you what to learn next or what career path to follow. But there are some facts about the south of France that you could learn that might help you make that decision, and there are some facts about web development, desktop game development and so on that could be useful in making career decisions.

One thing you could do without even asking a question is to look at questions on SO about those technologies. Do they get answered quickly? Is it easy to get help? Are lots of people using them? Another thing you could do is ask very crisp and specific questions about your technologies. Not "how long does it take to learn this?" kind of questions (which no-one can answer) but "what desktop platforms can I target with a game written with [framework]?" kind of questions. In this way you are gathering the information you need to make your decision.

Don't ever ask what you should do, because we can't decide for you. But use the right sites to ask answerable technical questions that will add up to your decision. It's more work, but it's the only way to do it. See also my answers to [Where to ask questions about personal life decisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216266/where-to-ask-questions-about-personal-life-decisions/216269#216269) and [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/185482#185482)