# Right place to ask a "discussion" question (I'm setting up a blog, what should....)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm pretty sure this isn't the right place to ask this. I'm not aware of a stack site out there where this question would fit. If someone could point me to the right place it would be awesome.

The question I was going to ask is:

> I am incorporating a blogging feature into my car enthusiast site. I want each user to be able to have their own blog and be able to browse other people's blogs. What blog engine would be best for this scenario?
>
> I am using ASP MVC 4 and found http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/ to look promising; however, I am a bit confused at the setup. This seems to be a blog set up for a personal site and not a "Nest of blogs" type of system. I've never done a blog before so I'm fresh meat here.

Comment: The question in its current form wouldn't belong on any SE site.  It's pretty much a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  [See also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/135887).

Comment: That's the problem with SE, it's totally inflexible. Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. You're looking for (sigh) a forum.

Comment: @bjb568 Ew. Forums. Gross. Does your mother know you talk that way?

Comment: I wish there was a forum as widely used as SE is! That would be magnificent.

Comment: One default approach to this problem is Wordpress MU: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 5):

If you can add a few details to your question and make it a bit more specific, and perhaps put a bit more effort in researching the available choices, then the closest fit would be [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). However, as is your question isn't on par with the SR community's general expectations:

- [How to ask and answer software recommendation questions - aka 'The Ground Rules'](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules)
- [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

If, after reading those discussions, you still aren't sure on how to phrase your question, you should drop by [SR's main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) and ask the regulars for feedback.