# Why does link to Meta Stack Exchange give Error (The question could not be loaded) on iOS app?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, meta, ios-app, redirection

On the Desktop version of GIS Stack Exchange I am able to click from

1. **[Should Shopping List Questions be Off Topic (and Closed) on GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-shopping-list-questions-be-off-topic-and-closed-on-gis-stack-exchange)**

to 2. **[Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)** (which redirects from a Meta Stack Overflow to a Meta Stack Exchange link)

without a problem.

However, when I try to do the same on the alpha (0.1.54) iOS application I get:

> Error
>
> The question could not be loaded.

[image]

Can anyone else reproduce this?

Note: You must go through the first link to the second one in order to see this.  I can go direct to the second link on the iOS app without seeing the error.

I could fix the link in the original Question but I think it is better to leave it as-is for now so that it can be investigated.

Comment: If you see the link carefully from PC browser, the link points to Meta SO, then redirect to Meta SE. Seems that the app cannot handle double redirection. OOT: repro'd on Android app too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Community user has gone through Meta GIS and changed all Meta StackOverflow links to Meta Stack Exchange. Consequently, the issue I reported in this Question is no longer reproducible.

Comment: Yep, this is it.  Feel free to mark this as the answer when it's eligible.