# Android App cannot handle redirection after MSE/MSO split

Tags: bug, android-app, redirection, mso-mse-split

*This bug report extends the same report from iOS counterpart: [Why does link to Meta Stack Exchange give Error (The question could not be loaded) on iOS app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230104/).*

When opening a link to old MSO that redirects to MSE (ex: [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)), the app will show:

> The question is not available, it may have been deleted.

instead of opening [the question in MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad).

- Stack Exchange: 1.0.31
- Android model: Nexus 4
- Android version: 4.4.2

**P.S. Community user has migrated all MSO links to its MSE counterpart.**

Comment: +1, I can reproduce this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long consideration, I feel that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), since the app doesn't know whether it's a genuine MSO post, or migrated MSE post.

Also, Community user has migrated all MSO links (except in the code-block) [since April 23 '14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=2534) to its MSE counterpart, so the issue should have been already mitigated.