# Can't view featured meta posts

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app, android-app-feed, featured-tag

I've just seen the [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/267557) post appear in my feed but when clicking on it I get a message saying "The question is not available, it may have been deleted.". If I go to the site in my browser I can see the post so it clearly hasn't been deleted.

I've seen this happen with a few other featured posts before as well but had forgotten to report it.

[image: Feed]
[image: Error message]

App version: 1.0.47

Comment: For some reason the app thinks the question was posted on MSO while it's actually posted in MSE.

Comment: Related?: [Android App cannot handle redirection after MSE/MSO split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230107/). Agree it's weird that the app shows MSO, not MSE icon though...

Comment: Declining because this was a one-off event and there's really nothing more to fix since the feed shouldn't do it again.