# Where can I ask about document indexing engines?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask what the best document indexing tool is, with a preference towards Windows... I would normally ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com), but I am not sure it's the right place.

Comment: You should know by now to tag with [meta-tag:site-recommendation].

Comment: opps.... sorry, I did know that, but in my haste hit the wrong one. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 2):

The only suitable site would be [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) but in its current form your question would be closed there as it does not define sufficient criteria for people to answer it properly.

What exactly would make an answer "best"? You need to provide a [purpose and objective requirements](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before your question would be acceptable there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a suitable site to ask this question. Firstly, it's subjective ("*What is the best*") which is typically unwelcome on all SE sites. Secondly, it's [a shopping list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) that encourages lots of answers and links to external tools, which will date quickly.

You may be best asking the question on another Q&A network entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) ... So I looked at the shopping list "debate", personally I am all for it - but I see the point.