# Which SE site should I use to ask about big data courses?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask about big data courses?

I want to get opinions on what free online courses I can enroll.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you use the keyword "*opinions*" the answer is: None. Use <strike>Reddit</strike> any other site you'd like.

Stack Exchange is for *questions and answers*, not for gathering *opinions*.

Another option might also be to search Google, find some options, read some reviews about them if available, and try to build your own opinion.

Answer (score 7):

There are really only two sites that take recommendation questions - [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) and [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) (the clue is in the name). Virtually all other sites actively discourage recommendations for the reasons outlined in the close reason from Stack Overflow:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

The two recommendation sites have strict rules about what constitutes a good question for them, but your questions wouldn't fall into their scope anyway.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to get opinions

That makes the question unsuitable to Stack Exchange sites.