# Where to ask computer science education question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding a few courses I have found, I would like to know the best one based on certain criteria. The criteria being: 
closest to actual computer science class, most authentic, and most trustworthy.

Basically, I have done a lot of research to come up with three open source courses, and want to know which one to use to have the same education as a BS in CS. Which site would handle this question best?

These courses require no opinions. They simply need to be seen, and matched to real world classes. An opinion would be, "which one is better?", my question is, "which course actually meets real requirements?". Not an opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which SE site should I use to ask about big data courses?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268479/which-se-site-should-i-use-to-ask-about-big-data-courses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that this question is on-topic for any Stack Exchange site because it would appear likely to be closed as seeking answers which are "primarily opinion-based".

You may be able to ask it in one of the computer science chat rooms but I think you should get to know at least one of those communities first by asking and answering a few questions.

Comment: That is what I assumed, but I have been on every site I can think of, and not even one person has given me an answer. Could you link some of these forums?

Answer (score 1):

This could be on-topic on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) - they have an [education tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education), but be careful: [a](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57588/30354) [lot](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48449/30354) [of](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42493/30354) [questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33803/30354) have been closed for being primarily opinion based or too broad. Your question might suffer the same fate, but with sufficient research you might give it a try.