# Where can I ask questions about career book recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> I am looking for a book for a first month at a new job.

Where can I ask questions like this?

Comment: I think `Google` is a best solution for it....

Comment: @mmushtaq i did already, couldn't find

Comment: Amazon has reviews and the ability to sort by review rank.

Answer (score 2):

Questions asking to recommend a book, or another off-site resource, are generally not well received on Stack Exchange, as

> they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

<sub>(from the Stack Overflow [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))</sub>

You might find related questions at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but I think this particular question would be closed. See also [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/295232) and a [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) by Jeff Atwoord for this reasons behind this policy.