# Where to ask questions in regards to a needed website module?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need a plugin or script that helps me find broken embedded YouTube videos on my website.

Which is the correct section on Stack Exchange to ask this?

Comment: There probably isn't one. We generally don't allow questions asking us to search for or recommend things. You could change it to be on-topic somewhere if you concentrated on the problem and your attempts to solve it. Such attempts should be more than "I googled and found nothing"

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation questions are not a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A model: see [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/295232)

That said, this has the potential to be a reasonably scoped request and you could try posting it on a site specialized in your website's framework:

- [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)
- [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/)
- [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)

Otherwise, you might want to give [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) a try. Be sure to read their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before posting there; this (of course) holds true for the other websites as well.