# On what Stack Exchange site should questions be asked that are about cannot find a certain product?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

To be specific. I am currently looking for a new wallet, but the ones that are on the internet do not match my criteria. Normally I ask software related questions on stackexchange sites, but I saw that there are also other topics like [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/). Now I wonder whether questions like could someone suggest what wallet brand matches the following criteria? are on-topic on one of the stack exchange sites.

Comment: They are [shopping list questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/295232) and generally not a good fit for Q&A sites like the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no SE site for that. There's only two sites for recommendations - Hardware Recommendations and Software Recommendations, and both are for PC questions. They were both experimental to an extent.

I kind of suspect something like this would be difficult to scope and most of the reasoning that [most sites don't allow shopping questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) would be true for a question like this.

Amusingly, my favourite site for recommendations like that - [wirecutter](https://thewirecutter.com) has none either. Its just one of those hard. super personal questions.