# Where to discuss which (email) provider to choose?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I started a post about which mail provider to use in (the community) webapps. This was flagged off-topic because webapps does not allow questions for recommendations. They sent me over to softwarerecs but as I expected that is off-topic over there because its not about finding a software but about finding a provider. Now again someone at softwarerecs recommends to use stackexchange - but stackexchange is for developing own software, the the wrong place again. So which community is teh right place to ask this? I cannot believe that nobody ever asked for recommending a service provider of any kind (mail, ftp, vServer, ISP ...)

webapps-post: 
[Looking for a webmail provider that allows email aliases and does not enforce giving a (mobile) phone number](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115777/looking-for-a-webmail-provider-that-allows-email-aliases-and-does-not-enforce-gi)

Comment: https://quora.com ? Recommendation questions don't work well on Stack Exchange's Q&A format.

Comment: _"I cannot believe that nobody ever asked for recommending a service provider of any kind"_ - They have, and they've always been told that it's off-topic.

Comment: Well, If I ask for a provider matching specific criteria (Q) and someone recommend one (A) this does fit Q&A ?! Its not about discussing pros and cons of different providers. I don't see any conceptional difference to e.g. how to implement XYZ.
--------
I dont know anything about quora.com , but accoring to wikipedia, it is a Q&A site, just as SE is. The advantage of the a SE network is obviously the focus on IT/Technology so its probably more likely to get a good and correct answer.

Comment: @EdgarHover nope it's still a recommendation, it's still not allowed and it would still get closed as off-topic.

Comment: quora claima being about exchanging knowledge but when you visit the website it seems that you have to register before even being able to see the structure or any of the other's people's Q&As. Weird concept.

Comment: @Robert Longson the entire softwarerecs community is about recommendations so it seems to work in the Q&A format. SE itself consists of recommendations of implementation techniques. So how can anyone claim that recommendations do not fit the SE Q&A format (and recommend an other website using the same format of discussion)

Comment: softwarerecst is very low volume and suffers badly from poor quality questions even so. SE contains examples, not recommendations. Recommendations were tried on a site called programmers, it didn't end well.

Answer (score 5):

Beyond the two recommendations sites, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), there are no other sites that are open for that type of questions.

In general those type of questions are at best valuable for the OP but not for the feature visitors, the answers go stale quickly, often the recommendation is opinion based and is a honey pot for spam.

These experiences from the past lead to the general rule to declare recommendation questions off-topic. See [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) and [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

To answer your question:

> So which community is the right place to ask : "Where to discuss which (email) provider to choose?"

There are no sites within the Stack Exchange network that will take that question. One of the more traditional forums are better suited for what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, which one? Its not that I never asked this (or similar) question in "traditional" forums. But it seems that many of those lack the experience and knowledge of the SE communities or the spirit to share the information. ----- If HW and SW recommendations are welcome and have own communities, why is there no "provider recommendations" community? I understand why to distinguish between hardware, software and providers - but I dont understand why HW and SW fit the Q&A format and providers dont ?!

Comment: They only fit because they have a very strict protocol to maintain their question quality. You might want to try to start something on Area51 but do search for earlier failed attemtps because IIRC there was at least one that never made it to beta. As for Which one: I'm already glad I can work out what goes where with in the SE network. Don't expect me to also get up to speed with the numerous fora out in the wild.

Comment: So SE network does not want this kind of question, got it. But I would be great if anyone could recommend a tech-focussed place to ask. I'd really like to avoid to google "email provider", (try to) register at dozens of those in the end maybe overseeing the essential feature(s) of the request in the WebUI in the end.

Comment: Quora, Reddit, [msdn social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home), and if you have to: Experts-Exchange