# Is there a Stack Exchange site for product recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Searching for things online is pretty easy since the invention of search engines. However, there are situations, where you are searching for a product with specific details, which can be a very long process.

For example, just a couple of days ago I was searching for an open-source talking caller ID app for Android, and it was very hard for me to find one finally. (Just incase someone came here from a search engine, the app I have found is called Announcify.)

So, is there such a thing as a Stack Exchange site for asking other people if such a thing exists, or is it allowed to ask if such a thing exists on the product's related Stack Exchange site? That is for example, if you are asking if a programming tool exists, can you ask it on Stack Overflow? If no, why isn't this the case? It would be very helpful.

Comment: I doubt that providing free product research would be at the top of many peoples' lists of how to spend free time, besides, OP's are notoriously bad at defining what it is that they actaully want, and so such research efforts would likely be wasted:(

Comment: For software you can try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and a similar site exists for Hardware but beyond that none of such sites exist and recommendation question are off-limits on all other sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sites dedicated to recommendations there are:

- [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)
- [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

They do have some strict quality guidelines you need to follow though so make sure you read through those first. See e.g. [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/22832) (for Software Recommendations) and [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) for (Hardware Recommendations).

As for recommendation questions on other general sites, they are generally off-topic. See [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/307988) for some reasoning behind that. They may be acceptable on some sites so it's worth having a look on a sites [help/on-topic](/help/on-topic) page and searching existing questions and that site's meta first (and asking on that site's meta if that doesn't fully clarify it for you).

I will say that even if they aren't explicitly off-topic you will need to be very specific and put in a lot of effort (showing your own research etc.) for your question to have a chance of being well-received.