# Where should I ask a question about trying VR sets in my country before buying one?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I need help with the following question or where to ask it.

TL;DR - Where can I try VR in Portugal before buying or where to ask this?

I'm from the north of Portugal and I'm looking to buy a virtual reality set, but before I do, since I have never tried any of them, I was looking to find a place/store where I can try them (free or paid) so I can decide on which one to buy (online) since the price, quality and features vary between products (Oculus Rift, HTC Vive, Vive Pro).

Seeing from the amount of information, videos and reviews online gave me a good idea of the differences between them but not as real as actually trying them out.

I posted this question here in this site after seeing the [amount of questions asking where to ask their questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+should+I+ask) And because I really don't know where to ask this.

Comment: This site is the meta site for Stack Exchange, as such, questions have to be about the Stack Exchange network. We're more than happy to let you know if there are any sites on our network that meet your needs (I'm guessing not) but asking where on the wider internet is beyond our scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the [right place](/help/whats-meta) to ask this [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) question about your question. Unfortunately, I don't think your actual question can't be answered on any Stack Exchange site; essentially, it's a [shopping list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/295232):

> The main arguments against "shopping list questions" are:
>
> - They are open-ended; there is never one perfect answer to them.
> - They outdate **incredibly** quickly. This was what turned me against shopping list questions: if you look around on Stack Overflow, you will find plenty of 2010 "what's the best xyz" questions whose answers are hideously outdated now.
> - They tend to attract a lot of spam and/or link only answers

Virtual Reality is a very young topic and the risk of outdated information is rather high. For all we know, in a few years we could be buying these things *en masse* in your local Walmart equivalent.

I think you're better off at a site outside the Stack Exchange network, e.g. [Quora](http://quora.com).