# Site recommendation for questions about Masonry?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was originally going to ask this question on Earth Science, but I figured this question had to do with asking how stones and large rocks are shaped for a given purpose.

The title of my question is:

> What kind of tools are used in today's era to carve stones or large rocks in masonry?

Comment: Sounds like a list question, which is off-topic on most or all SE sites.

Comment: I had the same concern as @S.L.Barth, and almost mentioned that in my answer; for now, I'm assuming your question body will have more details about a specific situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a list question. Could you explain what that means, and why it is off-topic on most or all SE sites?
Thanks!

Comment: This is an old post, but still pretty good: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: A list question is a question that asks for a list - like "all countries where X". Asking for a list of things, for which a certain property holds - is quickly a question that is too broad. (The shopping list question, in @SOLO's link, is a special case of this). Even "all tools used in today's era for doing X" may quickly result in  a list that is longer than a Stack Exchange answer can support, as a good answer will not just name the tools, but also show them and have a short explanation how each is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought for this is Home Improvement SE, also known as DIY SE. Building-related stuff is [on-topic there](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There's even already [a masonry tag](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masonry?sort=newest&days=365) there.

I think you're right to avoid Earth Science; that site is more about stones from a natural/geologic perspective.