# Where to ask questions about which GitHub plan (Free, Pro, Team or Enterprise) are best?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question about which GitHub plan (Free, Pro, Team or Enterprise) would be best for the start-up company I'm working in currently.  Is there a recommended Stack Exchange forum for this?

Before somebody responds "Contact GitHub", I suspect they will try to sell me the most expensive plan.  I need an unbiased recommendation, therefore I would like to hear from others in the community rather than a GitHub rep.

Comment: recommendation questions are basically banned across the SE network. Try chat.

Comment: @rene There are at least two exceptions [softwarerecs.se] & [hardwarerecs.se] :)

Comment: @Rubén none of those apply in this case, I already checked

Comment: Most companies will sell you the plan you need, not push the most expensive one. They want you to get value out of the product and if they put you in a tier with features you don’t need, you’ll be unhappy and might get rid of their service entirely. It’s in their best interest to find the right fit if they want to keep you as a customer. I’d give it a try first and then maybe take their recommendation and see if it makes sense. They shouldn’t be charging you for the consultation so you won’t lose anything by it.

Comment: Most companies will outright lie to you what is the "most popular choice" to get you to choose a more expensive plan (Not mentioning any specific site here). The suggested plan is usually not the most expensive plan but the second most expensive one, which is just another part of the psychological marketing to get you to believe that you need that plan.

Answer (score 5):

That specific question should not be asked on any SE site and to be honest nowhere on the internet.

In the scope of the SE network it was decided a while ago that shopping / recommendation questions are off-topic:

[Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

And your specific question falls in that category. You can't expect users that are volunteering their time to do a thorough analysis of current GitHub offerings and an assessment of your start-up needs, now and on the future. And if someone does, how do you verify that they did a fine job?

At best you can do is make the analysis on your own and then see if there are specific items that are unclear. I still advice to seek assistance in chat or on a traditional forum as there are no sites in the SE network that will take such questions. I checked the Meta of [Software recommednations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic) but finding an provider is off-topic there.

There used to be a [Start-up Business](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) site but it was closed 5 years ago and I don't have info on their scope so can't tell if it would have been on-topic there. (I realize this is not helping, it is more to have a few cases covered in case a site decides to bring these type of questions in scope)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of sites listed in https://stackexchange.com/sites but I don't think that you will find any site for shopping recommendations today. Maybe somewhere there is a community that could be interested in making a site proposal.

One of the main problems with the question is that it's very likely that question will be only helpful  to you, the possible answers will be primarily opinion-based and they could be obsolete just after they were posted.

Anyway there are several sites on SE about the technical part of GitHub (see [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691))

Reference

- [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/289691)