# May I ask anywhere on Stack Exchange about recommendations for drones having certain specifications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know what models of drone out there, if they exist, comply with my requirements (objective requirements).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drone are on-topic on [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), where they're called [unmanned aerial vehicles](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unmanned-aerial-vehicle). However, your question looks like a [shopping recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/295232) which are off-topic on almost all Stack Exchange sites. *Almost*; we make an exception for [software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), and it turns out the latter site welcomes [questions about drones](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone).

Answer (score 9):

A new site is about to be created for drones and model aircraft.

Take a look [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123448/drones-and-model-aircraft), for more information.

If you join Area 51, you can also help contribute to the new site!

Answer (score 6):

There is [SE Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to meet their policies when asking your question please.