# Proper SE Site to ask about freelancing consideration ( like best price suggestion, freelancer sites )

Tags: support, suggested-edits, site-recommendation

I like to ask this question, which i think is correct to asking in ***electronic SE site*** because i asked some question there ( maybe [Freelancer SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) also be good ) but i prrefferd to ask here ( and think need some **edite-suggestion** also) for better resualt and ...

The question is :

I like to know the proper  suggestion items for this freelancering designing  of heater mattress, With these reqiurments :

I have found from this [free patent site](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/9781772.pdf)( doubt it is really free or illegal!!).

Based on it, i think most important parts is [user friendly and fast responsiblity of controller part](https://supercomfysleep.com/best-heated-mattress-pads/) and  using safe and long life ( [10 years](http://Electric%20Blanket%20Buying%20Tips%20-%20Electric%20Blanket%20Safety)) and cheap element for power supply and using proper MOSFET or SRC ic as CURRENT CONTRLOLLER and finally the proper temperature sensor ( i dont think LM35 be good suggestion). The main parts are here :

[image]

And suggested circuit (based above discussed free patent):

[image]

One commercial mode is like [this](https://www.tradekorea.com/product/detail/P357187/Aqua-Bed-Warmer-T-Series-Heated-Mattress-Pad.html) :

[image]

And having some blanket heater PCB photo captured from [beurer company](https://www.carestore.ie/beurer-cosy-cape.html) which its internal circuit have one atiny24a AVR IC and [X0402ME](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/newjerseysemiconductor/X0402MF.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwid3uiWoOjmAhXEtlkKHUiFCgMQFjALegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1-vxf3oXi964_8-tjr7FjY) IC as Thristor like this:

I have seen some [post like this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=393243.0), which suggested to use pid controller for temperature controlling.

also need to work on [ist standards](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/03/Bedding_EN.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjU2__IrujmAhVRY1AKHXM4DGAQFjABegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3Y7UTFUHbSkW2ScBJ2z6I6) (like ul964 and ... ) i prefer to have confirmation of  have some fast heating process at start until reaching the target temperature ( max would be below 140. F or 60 celsius) and  wi-fi or bluetooth connection to have more controlling on it ( like having used body temperature monitoring diagram)  for elderly families and user suggestion heating pattern as user request which could be updated from android app and user feedback (maybe need one speaker also for communicate between user and app for getting feedback or  ... ) as  vip version which designed for communicating for other devices for better improvement in user satisfaction as ...

Also some more EMFs protection based of [this post](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-om-lge&ei=-awPXrStFfaEk74P8I-Y8As&q=UL%20964Standard%20for%20Electrically%20Heated%20Bedding%20pdf%20UL%20964&oq=UL%20964Standard%20for%20Electrically%20Heated%20Bedding%20pdf%20UL%20964&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..30i10.15912.18951..19167...1.0..0.579.5562.3-5j4j4......0....1.yfpv-_PayJA):

> Electric and magnetic fields (EMFs) have been hypothesized to increase
>
> the risk of breast cancer, and electric blankets represent an
>
> important source of exposure to EMFs. The authors examined the
>
> relation between electric blanket use and invasive breast cancer in
>
> the Nurses' Health Study.

And overheating protection based this [site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_blanket&ved=2ahUKEwjgo7eptOjmAhVOrxoKHWfZAiMQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1wqh6ZkyQvQC7T-hZusCsg) recommendations:

> Newer electric blankets have a shutoff mechanism to prevent
>
> the blanket from overheating or catching fire. Older blankets (prior
>
> to about 2001) may not have a shut-off mechanism; users run the risk
>
> of overheating. Older blankets are considered fire hazards

So i have not enough time for doing it and like to start exporting my electronic requirements into electronic freelancers  efficiently.

Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking many questions. What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Only based on the title:

> Proper SE Site to ask about freelancing consideration (like best price suggestion, freelancer sites)

No site within the SE network is suitable for that question. What you're asking is a recommendation question, looking for an off-site resource or more popular expressed: a shopping question. Those type of question are not a good fit for the Q/A model as they are only applicable to very few future visitors, go stale quickly and worst of all they attract SPAM posts.

See also: [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

The Freelancing.se site is **not** an option because their [helpcenter explicitly exclude that](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> and isn't about...
>   ...
>   Marketing or finding Freelancers within the site to complete your work

Use a tradiotional forum, like Quora or reddit, to name a few.